# JQuery dependency: blown up

Tags: javascript, jquery, solution-explorer

I face this problem. I'm getting this message in the Solution Explorer: jQuery not installed

[image]

I don't have any idea why it shows like this since I have it 'installed'

[image]

But right now a lot of warning started to pop up with different messages:

Code unaccesible
'}' missing (they indeed are missing but it changed on its own!)
duplicated identificators

All this happening in JS files.

[image]

And of course, my JScripts inside my views are not working at all. Any idea why and how this can be fixed?

Thanks in advance

**Update:**

Installed JQuery (3.2.1) thru Bower. The warning sign in the solution explorer is gone. However the rest of warning and this new error pop-d up:

Translation:
Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type. The 'require' variable must be of type 'NodeRequire', but here it has the 'Require' type.

[image]

Comment: Well, compare the name of the package with the name that has the error. "jquery" !== "jQuery". try removing "jQuery" and adding "jquery".

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I actually went the other way and installed jQuery (3.2.1) No error on the Solution Explorer but all those warning still there